# Can I cast Tactical Advantage multiple times on the same creature?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I'm new to Magic the Gathering. I have a question about Instants and [Tactical Advantage](https://www.mtgassist.com/cards/Arena-New-Player-Experience/Tactical-Advantage/):

> Target blocking or blocked creature you control gets +2/+2 until end of turn.

Am I allowed to use 2 Tactical Advantages in a row on the same creature on the same turn, if I have enough mana? So I'd bring my creature up +4/+4.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes, you can cast as many spells as you want on the same creature.**

The targeting requirements for Tactical Advantage are that it must be a creature you control, and it must be blocking or being blocked. Tactical Advantage changes none of these properties, so the second Tactical Advantage is just as legal to cast as the first.